# Using keen.io from a service worker

Tags: javascript, keen-io

How can I use keen.io from a service worker? It would seem the [javascript sdk](https://github.com/keen/keen-js) has no service worker support (no xhr/jsonp/beacon in a SW), and calling fetch directly returns cors errors (`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`).

Without proxying via a server, is there any other way to post data to keen.io?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your error and/or any sample of the code you are trying to post?

Comment: Could you link to the specific version of the JavaScript SDK that you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you by chance have an adblocker/privacybadger, or firewall, that would be blocking these requests?

Comment: thanks! I didnt think adblock would affect a service worker, but it looks like it does.